# How to implement a YouTrack REST API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, youtrack

I would like to have my .Net C# program automatically create YouTrack tickets when things go south using their REST API.  Can anyone point me to a C# implementation or guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[YouTrackSharp](https://github.com/hhariri/YouTrackSharp) would be a good start.

Comment: Assuming it works, which given the authors I have very little doubt, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Too bad I couldn't find it in a google search!

Comment: PLease let me know if you have any issues with it. Either contact me directly (@hhariri) or file an issue at http://youtrack.codebetter.com.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repo mentioned by CrazyCoder seems to be orphaned.
Here's the official JetBrains repo, which appears to be currently being maintained: [YouTrackSharp](https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackSharp)